# How to print a series upto n terms, with each term = sum of previous three terms and first term=1 then 2 3 6 11

Tags: c, loops

I am not understanding why my code isn't showing right output. For example: input of `n=5` should give output `1 2 3 6 11` but it gives output `1 1 0 0 0`. Can you please suggest some improvement in my  code?

My code  works on the principle similar to  Fibonacci series. Instead of adding 2 previous terms it adds previous 3 terms.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a=0,b=1,c=0,i,n,s;  //To print  s=1(first term)
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      s=a+b+c;
      printf("%d ",s);//for first time it will print 1.

      s=c;//for second term value of s=1 will be pasted in c. 
      c=b; //for second term value of c=0 will be pasted in b.
      b=a; //for second term value of b=1 will be pasted in a.
    }    //loop will go back to first step and print s=1+0+1=2(second term)
     and so on ,3,6,11....

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output for `n=5` to be

> 1,2,3,6,11

but actual output is

> 1 1 0 0 0

Comment: You need to swap your assignments. `c=b;` => `b=c;`

Comment: Fine its working.Can you also tell me how to print only the nth number of the loop ;ex n= 5 output should only print 13??not whole loop 1 2  4 7 13

Comment: You probably mean 11? If you don't want to print in the loop, move your print statement behind the loop.

Comment: Use `int main(void)`: C17::6.11.6: *"Function declarators The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature."*

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the values incorrectly. You are also assigning s = c, which is incorrect as it is not being used in future.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
    int a=0,b=1,c=0,i,n,s;  //To print  s=1(first term)
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    s=a+b+c;
    printf("%d ",s);//for first time it will print 1.

    // The values you were swapping was in reverse order.
    a = b;
    b = c; 
    c = s; 
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how to print only the nth number of the loop ;ex n= 5 output should only print 13??not whole loop 1 2  4 7 13

Comment: print when i = n

Answer (score 0):

You have the assignment statements reversed. `s=c;` puts the value of `c` is `s`, but you want the value of `s` in `c`.

You can fix that by reversing each assignment, but then you will be changing `c` before it is stored in `b` and changing `b` before it is stored in `a`. To fix that, reverse the order of the assignments, so `a` is assigned first:

```
a = b;
b = c;
c = s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your assignments the wrong way around:

```
s=c;//for second term value of s=1 will be pasted in c. 
c=b; //for second term value of c=0 will be pasted in b.
b=a; //for second term value of b=1 will be pasted in a.
```

This should be

```
a = b; //for second term value of b=1 will be pasted in a.
b = c; //for second term value of c=0 will be pasted in b.
c = s;//for second term value of s=1 will be pasted in c.
```

Answer (score -1):

1. The initial values should be `0,0,1` for `a,b,c` respectively
2. In this case you will get an array of `1 2 4 7 13`
3. You have assigned the values for `a,b,c` in the reverse order.

The modified code is below.

```
int main() 
{
    int a=0,b=0,c=1,i,n,s;  //To print  s=1(first term)
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        s=a+b+c;
        printf("%d ",s);//for first time it will print 1.
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c=s;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Output for n = 5 is

> 1 2 4 7 13

**Edit**

To print the value of nth term, you need to move the `printf` to the end of the loop.

If `n` is very large, you can consider not having a loop itself, deriving the formula for the nth term and using that directly.